# Trying to filter out matching records from 2 array as 1 array have different structure

Tags: javascript

Below is my sample records :

```
var array1 = [
    {
      "testId": 15,
      "child": [
        {
          "variantId": 100,
          "name": "A1",
        },
        {
          "variantId": 200,
          "name": "A2",
        },
        {
          "variantId": 300,
          "name": "A3",
        },
        {
          "variantId": 400,
          "name": "A4",
        },
        {
          "variantId": 500,
          "name": "A5",
        }
      ]
    }
]


var array2=
[
    {
      "variantId": 100,
      "tests": [
        {
          "testId": 15,
          "flag" : true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "variantId": 200,
      "tests": [
        {
          "testId": 15,
          "flag" : false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "variantId": 400,
      "tests": [
        {
          "testId": 15,
          "flag" : true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "variantId": 500,
      "tests": [
        {
          "testId": 15,
          "flag" : true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

At first I will fetch selected testId record from Array1. Now I would like to select only those variantId from array2 whose flag is true. For example, from inputs ,`VariantIds will be 100,400 and 500`.

Now with this selected variantsIds from array2 I want fetch only matching variantIds, so from Array2 I want to search `100,400 and 500` in Array1 and select only matching records from Array1.

**Expected output :**

```
"child": [
        {
          "variantId": 100,
          "name": "A1",
        },
        {
          "variantId": 400,
          "name": "A4",
        },
        {
          "variantId": 500,
          "name": "A5",
        }
      ]
```

So far I am successful in getting specific TestId record from array1 but now I am not getting how to filter out variantIds from array1 as structure of array2 is little complex.

```js
var array1 = [
    {
      "testId": 15,
      "child": [
        {
          "variantId": 100,
          "name": "A1",
        },
        {
          "variantId": 200,
          "name": "A2",
        },
        {
          "variantId": 300,
          "name": "A3",
        },
        {
          "variantId": 400,
          "name": "A4",
        },
        {
          "variantId": 500,
          "name": "A5",
        }
      ]
    }
]

var array2=
[
    {
      "variantId": 100,
      "tests": [
        {
          "testId": 14,
          "flag" : true
        },
        {
          "testId": 15,
          "flag" : true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "variantId": 200,
      "tests": [
        {
          "testId": 14,
          "flag" : true
        },
        {
          "testId": 15,
          "flag" : false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "variantId": 400,
      "tests": [
        {
          "testId": 14,
          "flag" : true
        },
        {
          "testId": 15,
          "flag" : true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "variantId": 500,
      "tests": [
        {
          "testId": 14,
          "flag" : true
        },
        {
          "testId": 15,
          "flag" : true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
  
  
var testId = 15;

var testObj ={};
 for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            if (array1[i].testId == testId) {
                testObj = array1[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        console.log(testObj);
```

Comment: It's definitely doable, but highly inefficient. Is there a reason your data is structured like this, and a reason that `"tests"` is not a part of the `"child"` object in the first array?

Comment: @mhodges :But test is a part of first array as notice variantIds 100,200,300,400,500 all belongs to testId=15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a hash table and get first all `true` flags, the filter the child array.

```js
function getChildren(data, flags, testId) {
    var hash = Object.create(null),
        result;

    flags.forEach(function (a) {
        a.tests.forEach(function (b) {
            b.testId === testId && b.flag && (hash[a.variantId] = true);
        });
    });

    data.forEach(function (a) {
        if (a.testId === testId) {
            result = {
                child: a.child.filter(function (b) {
                    return hash[b.variantId];
                })
            };
        }
    });
    return result;
}

var array1 = [{ testId: 15, child: [{ variantId: 100, name: "A1", }, { variantId: 200, name: "A2", }, { variantId: 300, name: "A3", }, { variantId: 400, name: "A4", }, { variantId: 500, name: "A5", }] }],
    array2 = [{ variantId: 100, tests: [{ testId: 15, flag: true }] }, { variantId: 200, tests: [{ testId: 15, flag: false }] }, { variantId: 400, tests: [{ testId: 15, flag: true }] }, { variantId: 500, tests: [{ testId: 15, flag: true }] }],
    array3 = [{ testId: 15, child: [{ variantId: 100, name: "A1", }, { variantId: 200, name: "A2", }, { variantId: 300, name: "A3", }, { variantId: 400, name: "A4", }, { variantId: 500, name: "A5", }] }],
    array4 = [{ variantId: 100, tests: [{ testId: 14, flag: true }, { testId: 15, flag: true }] }, { variantId: 200, tests: [{ testId: 14, flag: true }, { testId: 15, flag: false }] }, { variantId: 400, tests: [{ testId: 14, flag: true }, { testId: 15, flag: true }] }, { variantId: 500, tests: [{ testId: 14, flag: true }, { testId: 15, flag: true }] }],
    testId = 15;

console.log(getChildren(array1, array2, testId));
console.log(getChildren(array3, array4, testId));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Ok upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but 1 thing is i dont see use of my this variable : var testId = 15;Record should be selected from array1 and array2 for this testId=15 only.

Comment: You rock again like as usual.This worked.Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create one object and use it as hash table to filter `child` array from object in array1

```js
var array1 = [{"testId":15,"child":[{"variantId":100,"name":"A1"},{"variantId":200,"name":"A2"},{"variantId":300,"name":"A3"},{"variantId":400,"name":"A4"},{"variantId":500,"name":"A5"}]}, {"testId":14,"child":[{"variantId":100,"name":"A1"},{"variantId":200,"name":"A2"},{"variantId":300,"name":"A3"},{"variantId":400,"name":"A4"},{"variantId":500,"name":"A5"}]}]
var array2=[{"variantId":100,"tests":[{"testId":14,"flag":true},{"testId":15,"flag":true}]},{"variantId":200,"tests":[{"testId":14,"flag":true},{"testId":15,"flag":false}]},{"variantId":400,"tests":[{"testId":14,"flag":false},{"testId":15,"flag":true}]},{"variantId":500,"tests":[{"testId":14,"flag":true},{"testId":15,"flag":true}]}]

var obj = {}
array2.forEach(function(e) {
  e.tests.forEach(function(test) {
    if (test.flag) obj[e.variantId + '|' + test.testId] = true;
  })
})

var result = array1.reduce(function(r, e) {
  var o = {testId: e.testId,child: []}

  var child = e.child.filter(function(a) {
    return obj[a.variantId + '|' + e.testId]
  })
  
  o.child = child;
  r.push(o)
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4))
```

Comment: Consider if i am having multiple test records in array2 then your test[0] will not work and actually i am having list of tests in array2 for each of the variant.So i need to search testId in each of the variants tests

Comment: @Learning Then just use `.reduce()` on `array1` and concat the results of each `element.child.filter(...)` to a final array.

Comment: @Learning You should post your actual data.

Comment: Ok i have updated my question to include sample inputs for you in array2

Comment: @Learning Is my answer what you're looking for?

Comment: And in array1 you only have one object?

Comment: Upvoted your answer for your kind efforts towards helping me.I have updated my sample input in my running code.Array1 will holds multiple tests and each of the test will hold array of childs

Comment: So `child` array of each object in array1 should be filtered by objects in array2?

Comment: Yes that is right but from array2 i want to consider only those variantIds whose TestId=15 and flag is true

Comment: I think this is it, plase take a look https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1751/, it will filter all objects from array1 and create new array as result.

Comment: That last part can also look like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1752/, also as you can see you keep array1 unchanged.

Comment: Ok this is working but 1 thing i am not getting and that is i cant see the use of this variable:var testId = 15;
While selecting records from array1 and array2 i want to consider this variable :var testId = 15;

Answer (score 1):

Building off of Nenad's answer, to get this to work with multiple elements in `array1`, you can simply use `.reduce()` on `array1` and concat the results into a final array like so:

This also accounts for multiple tests in a variant and maps each testId with its corresponding flag value into an object to iterate over to create the final results.

```js
var array1 = [{"testId":15,"child":[{"variantId":100,"name":"A1"},{"variantId":200,"name":"A2"},{"variantId":300,"name":"A3"},{"variantId":400,"name":"A4"},{"variantId":500,"name":"A5"}]}]
var array2 = [{"variantId":100,"tests":[{"testId":15,"flag":true}]},{"variantId":200,"tests":[{"testId":15,"flag":false}]},{"variantId":400,"tests":[{"testId":15,"flag":true}]},{"variantId":500,"tests":[{"testId":15,"flag":true}]}]
var testId = 15;
var obj = array2.reduce(function(result, current) {
    // create object accessable by variantId and testIds
    result[current.variantId] = current.tests.reduce(function (res, curr) {
        if (curr.testId === testId) {
          res[curr.testId] = curr.flag;
        }
        return res;
    }, {});
    // result has the following structure: 
    // { "100": { "14": true, "15": true, ... }, ...} where 100 is the variantId
    //  14/15 are testIds and the boolean is the flag value of the testId
    return result;
}, {});

var result = array1.reduce(function (res, current) {
    return res.concat(current.child.filter(function(elem) {
      // ensure that both the variantId and the testId match and testId is true
      return obj[elem.variantId] && obj[elem.variantId][current.testId];
    }));
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: First of all i will upvote your answer because of your kind efforts towards helping me.Yes your answer is correct based on my sample input but from array 2 i would like to filter only Specific test i.e testId=15 with flag as true for each of the variants.

Comment: @Learning Ahh yes, I just noticed that when I saw your updated data. I will fix that shortly and let you know

Comment: I dont see any filter for TestId=15 in this part: result[current.variantId] = current.tests.reduce(function (res, curr) {

Comment: @Learning Are you only looking specifically for 15? I wrote this to accept whatever testId is given. That's the `res[curr.testId] = curr.flag`. That creates an object that looks like this `{ "14": true, "15": true }`. Then in the bottom reduce, it checks to see if the given testId is a part of that object, and if it is true or not.

Comment: Yes I am looking specifically for testId=15.it should not consider 14 as because my testId variable hold value 15

Comment: @Learning If your testId variable does not contain 14, it will not consider 14. If it contains 15, it will consider 15.

Comment: Yes that is right.as of now consider I just want records for testid 15 with flag as true from array2

Comment: @Learning Okay, If `array1` does not contain anything other than an object with `testId` === 15, that is exactly what my code does

Comment: But where you have use my this variable in your code :var testId = 15;??

Comment: @Learning See my updated code. You simply have to check for equality to the testId in `current.tests.reduce(...)`

Answer (score 1):

if you try this, and execute..

```
var expectedList = [];
for(var i =0; i < array1.length; i++){
    var obj =  array1[i];
    var childList = obj.child;
    for(var j =0; j < childList.length; i++){
        var childObj = childList[J];
        var key = childObj.variantId

        for(var l =0; l < array2.length; l++){
            var array2Obj = array2[l];
            if(array2Obj.variantId === key){
                var testList = array2.tests;
                for(var m =0; m < testList.length; m++){
                    var testObj = testList[m];
                    if(testObj.flag ===  true){
                        expectedList.push(obj);
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
console.log(expectedList)
```

Comment: yes @mhodges, And i'will improve my answer. Anyway thnks your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it as i have done in this code

```
var trueElements=array2.map(element=>{
     if(element.tests[0].testId == testId && element.tests[0].flag == true){
        return element.variantId;
    };
});


 var child = testObj.child.filter(element=>trueElements.indexOf(element.variantId)>-1));
```

Working snippet as below:

```js
    var array1 = [
        {
          "testId": 15,
          "child": [
            {
              "variantId": 100,
              "name": "A1",
            },
            {
              "variantId": 200,
              "name": "A2",
            },
            {
              "variantId": 300,
              "name": "A3",
            },
            {
              "variantId": 400,
              "name": "A4",
            },
            {
              "variantId": 500,
              "name": "A5",
            }
          ]
        }
    ]

    var array2=
    [
        {
          "variantId": 100,
          "tests": [
            {
              "testId": 15,
              "flag" : true
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "variantId": 200,
          "tests": [
            {
              "testId": 15,
              "flag" : false
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "variantId": 400,
          "tests": [
            {
              "testId": 15,
              "flag" : true
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "variantId": 500,
          "tests": [
            {
              "testId": 15,
              "flag" : true
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
      
      
    var testId = 15;

    var testObj ={};
     for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
                if (array1[i].testId == testId) {
                    testObj = array1[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            var trueElements= [];
trueElements=array2.map(element=>{
 if(element.tests[0].testId == testId && element.tests[0].flag == true){
return element.variantId;
};
});
 

 console.log(testObj.child.filter(element=>trueElements.indexOf(element.variantId)>-1));
```